# bash script: calculate sum size of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ls

I'm working on Linux and need to calculate the sum size of some files in a directory.

I've written a bash script named `cal.sh` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line
done<`ls -l | grep opencv | awk '{print $5}'`
```

However, when I executed this script `./cal.sh`, I got an error:

```
./cal.sh: line 6: `ls -l | grep opencv | awk  '{print $5}'`: ambiguous redirect
```

And if I execute it with `sh cal.sh`, it seems to work but I will get some weird message at the end of output:

```
25
31
385758: File name too long
```

Why does `sh cal.sh` seem to work? Where does `File name too long` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, as other answers will point out, it's not a good idea to parse the output of `ls` because it may vary between systems. But it's worth knowing why the script doesn't work.

The ambiguous redirect error is because you need quotes around your `ls` command i.e.:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  echo $line
done < "`ls -l | grep opencv | awk '{print $5}'`"
```

But this still doesn't do what you want. The "<" operator is expecting a filename, which is being defined here as the output of the `ls` command. But you don't want to read a file, you want to read the output of `ls`. For that you can use the "<<<" operator, also known as a "here string" i.e.:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line
done <<< "`ls -l | grep opencv | awk '{print $5}'`"
```

This works as expected, but has some drawbacks. When using a "here string" the command must first execute in full, then store the output of said command in a temporary variable. This can be a problem if the command takes long to execute or has a large output.

IMHO the best and most standard method of iterating a commands output line by line is the following:

```
ls -l | grep opencv | awk '{print $5} '| while read -r line ; do
    echo "line: $line"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can do:

```
du -cb *opencv* | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

option `-b` will display each file in bytes and `-c` will print the total size.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against using that pipeline to get the sizes of the files you want - in general parsing `ls` is something that you should avoid. Instead, you can just use `*opencv*` to get the files and `stat` to print the size:

```
stat -c %s *opencv*
```

The format specifier `%s` prints the size of each file in bytes.

You can pipe this to `awk` to get the sum:

```
stat -c %s *opencv* | awk '{ sum += $0 } END { if (sum) print sum }'
```

The `if` is there to ensure that no input => no output.